# how to toggle item from nested array in react

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, nested-object

I am struck in nested array and need help:
my data is:

```js
Data: [{
    name: "Steel Support, Aviation Lights, Std", // match parent array name
    code: "450W0619P001",
    reserved: [{
        serial: "one",
        selected: false // toggle this
      },
      {
        serial: "two",
        selected: true, // toggle this
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Lock Nut, Prevailing Torque, M12x1.75m", // match parent array name
    code: "450W0619P001",
    reserved: [{
        serial: "one",
        selected: true // toggle this
      },
      {
        serial: "two",
        selected: true // toggle this
      },
      {
        serial: "three",
        selected: false // toggle this
      },
    ],
  },
]

const [erpParts, setErpParts] = useState(Data);
```

Here is my function to toggle nested array object state. I need to **match parent array name** and then **toggle child array object** value.

```js
const selectPart = (parentArr, part) => {
  setErpParts(
    erpParts.map((x) => {
      if (x.name !== parentArr.name) return x;
      return { ...x,
        reserved: [...x.reserved, part.selected != part.selected]
      };
    })
  );
};
```

My function is not showing desired result. please look into this and help.

Answer (score 1):

This line will create a copy of `reserved` array and will add a new value boolean `false` to the copy:

```
reserved: [...x.reserved, part.selected != part.selected]
```

You have to map every item inside your array and updates its property
`selected`:

```
  const selectPart = (parentArr, part) => {
  setErpParts(erpParts =>
    erpParts.map(x => {
      if (x.name !== parentArr.name) return x
      else {
        const reservedUpdated = x.reserved.map(res => {
          if (res.serial === part.serial) {
            return {
              ...res,
              selected: !part.selected
            }
          } else {
            return res
          }
        })
        return {
          ...x,
          reserved: reservedUpdated
        }
      }
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. first time it is toggling the state but when I toggle again it toggled all objects of reserved array

Comment: So your goal is toggling one object instead all?

Comment: When you want to change the state using the old state like toggling you should use callback instead  of an object, you can try the last version of my answer

Comment: still no luck :( I am seeing the same issue. this is how I am calling the function you mentioned: `<View>
        {erpParts.map((part, i) => (
          <View key={i}>
            {part.reserved.map((currPart, i) => (
              <View key={i}>
                <Text>{currPart.serial}</Text>
                <Text>{currPart.selected ? "true" : "false"}</Text>
                <Button onPress={() => selectPart(part, currPart)}>Toggle</Button>
                <Divider />
              </View>
            ))}
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>`

Comment: first time it works fine but when I try to toggle again it toggle whole reserved array objects.

Comment: You should do a condition to detect your desired object, by comparing the field serial, check again the answer lol.

Comment: Please don't forget to check the answer :)